# How to detect if system supports ipv6?

Tags: perl, ipv6

I finally managed to fix ipv6 support in my software. Unfortunately, now it crashes on every ipv4 only machine. Here is the faulty subroutine:

```
sub init
{
    my ($self, %opts) = @_;

    # server options defaults
    my %defaults = (StartBackground => 0, ServerPort => 3000);

    # set options or use defaults
    map { $self->{$_} = (exists $opts{$_} ? $opts{$_} : $defaults{$_}) }
        keys %defaults;

    $self->{'server'} = HTTP::AppServer::Base->new($self->{'ServerPort'}, Socket::AF_INET6);

    return $self;
}
```

The problem here is in the second last line:

```
$self->{'server'} = HTTP::AppServer::Base->new($self->{'ServerPort'}, Socket::AF_INET6);
```

As on ipv4 only machine it dies complaining about a not supported address family (which is the second parameter passed to the `new` function).

Basically, what I need to do is:

```
if (it_supports_ipv6()) {
    $self->{'server'} = HTTP::AppServer::Base->new($self->{'ServerPort'}, Socket::AF_INET6);
}
else {
    $self->{'server'} = HTTP::AppServer::Base->new($self->{'ServerPort'});
}
```

But how to implement a function like `it_supports_ipv6()`?

I tried with `eval` with the following syntax, but it doesn't work:

```
my $ipv6_success = eval { $self->{'server'} = HTTP::AppServer::Base->new($self->{'ServerPort'}, Socket::AF_INET6); };
if (!defined($ipv6_success)) {
    $self->{'server'} = HTTP::AppServer::Base->new($self->{'ServerPort'});
}
```

The logic is that I've read in `eval` doc that it returns `undef` if the expression causes the program to die.

I'm working on a Linux machine.

Comment: Does it crash or does it just die? If it's merely dying, you can wrap the line with the `Socket::AF_INET6` reference in an [`eval`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#eval) call.

Comment: `Paraniod::Network::Socket` is a wrapper for Socket that supplies BOOL `has_ipv6()`

Comment: @mob, Yes, you're right, it dies! I will check eval.

Comment: @mob, I've tried with `eval` and I've added the try at the end of my post. Could you please explain me where I'm wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You check for a death inside your eaval by checking the $@ variable. It will contain the message from the die() call. If there's nothing in $@, then you didn't die and you can check your return value.   E.G.  eval { somthing }; is ($@) { warn "something went horribly wrong: $@"; }

Comment: @charlesbridge, That return false positive. Check my answer to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't trust the `has_ipv6()` function in `Paranoid::Network::Socket`. It returns false positive as it just checks if Perl supports it, but this isn't enough at all (the system, as example, could lack ipv6 kernel module loaded).

I ended up with the following function and it seems to work fine.

```
use IO::Socket::IP;

sub supports_ipv6 {
    my $has_ipv6;

    eval {
        $has_ipv6 = IO::Socket::IP->new (
            Domain => PF_INET6,
            LocalHost => '::1',
            Listen => 1 ) or die;
    };

    if ($@) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the presence of the `AF_INET6` constant by `eval`:

```
use constant HAS_AF_INET6 => defined eval { Socket::AF_INET6() };
```

But this isn't really sufficient; just because the OS supports that constant does not mean this specific machine supports it. You'd have to test that the entire `socket()` and `bind()` operation worked as well. For that you'd still want to somehow error-detect the actual object constructor.